# Changing varchar into integer in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot change varchar type into integer using SQL.
How can I do it ?
Please, help me.

Comment: Please add an example. It's not easy to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Please can you include the SQL you're trying and the values expected in pleasE?

Comment: I just want to change data type , data type is Varchar which has only numbers. So, I want to change this type to INT (integer) . So, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to do that while SELECTing the data? Or do you want to change the definition of the table column using `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: I want to change the definition of table column

Answer (score 2):

Just like @a_horse_with_no_name said, you can do it in two ways when selecting the data in a query or you can change the data type definition in the main table using ALTER statement.

Assuming your table is called employees and the field name you want to convert to integer is called emp_id;

**Option 1: Convert to Integer Data Type while Selecting Data**

```
SELECT
    CAST (emp_id AS INTEGER),
    name, address
FROM employees;
```

Or in this condensed form

```
SELECT
    emp_id::INTEGER,
    name, address
FROM employees;
```

**Option 2: Using ALTER Statement**

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ALTER COLUMN emp_id TYPE INT 
USING emp_id::INTEGER;
```